# Workflow leave management odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Hi I'm having a hard time trying to work out the permissions for the Human
Resources module of `Odoo10` when it comes to the Leave Management Workflow.

I active the double validation in the leave Type.
Let say I have a Department with the following employees:

```
Manager01 (Manager of the Department)
Employee01 (Employee on the same department)
```

I've initially set both `Manager01` and `Employee01` as Employee in the access rights for Human Resources. I also set Manager01 as Employee01's manager in the employee directory and set both persons in the same department. So the problem here is that if I want to do a leave request,

```
Employee01->Manager01->HR officier
```

Now, the leave request from employee to manager it ok working

[image]

but now from Manager01 to HR officier (second approve) don't work how can I 
do  it !!! what is the acces right can i assign to HR officer .

Comment: Interesting question, but has nothing to do with programming but configuring Odoo. You should ask that question in the [official Odoo forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1).

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign four access rights.
First for admin or super user
Second for Hr Officer
Third for the manager.
Fourth for the employee.